# Storing text from a text file into six different vectors (C++)

Tags: c++, vector

I need to store text from a text file into several different vectors. 
The text file would look something like this:
**1111
Dish Washer
20
250.50
550.50
2222
Micro Wave
75
150.00
400.00
3333
Cooking Range 
50 
450.00
850.00
4444
Circular Saw
150
45.00
125.00**

and my vectors are this:

```
vector<int> iID;
 vector<string> iName;
 vector<int> pOrdered;
 vector<int> pInStore;
 vector<double> manufPrice;
 vector<double> sPrice;
```

so the information from the text file would have to be iID, iName, pOrdered, pInStore, manufPrice, sPrice in that order but I am not sure on how to implement that kind of code.

Comment: Suggestion: Make a structure that aggregates all of the different types of data you need to read and store and make a single `vector` of this structure. You will find the book-keeping much easier to manage if you keep all of one data record in one place.

Comment: Side note: If you go with a single structure, you can easily write member functions (or free functions like the insertion (`<<`) and extraction (`>>`) operators) that can make the job very easy. Eg : `vector<mystruct> items;  mystruct item; while (infile >> item) items.push_back(item);` All done.

Comment: *I need to store text from a text file into several different vectors* -- The classic start to the [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/).  The difference is that we know what you're trying to accomplish without having to pry it out of you :)

Comment: Why is there a discrepancy between your input sample and the description of fields?  Given the first row, `iID[1111], iName[Dish Washer], pOrdered[20], pInstore[250.50], manufPrice[550.50], ?sPrice[2222]`?

Comment: Also, if you are using space as a field separator, you're going to have a difficult time reading the `iName` field.  Can't tell if the fields are tab separated.

Answer (score 0):

IMHO, you should stay away from parallel arrays and model the data using a `struct`:

```
struct Record
{
    int id;
    std::string name;
    int p_ordered;
    //...
    friend std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& input, Record& r);
};

std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& input, Record& r)
{
    input >> r.id;
    input >> r.name;
    //...
    return input;
}
```

Your input code could look like this:

```
std::vector<Record> database;
Record r;
while (infile >> r)
{
    database.push_back(r);
}
```

One issue with parallel arrays is there is a chance that they can get out of sync.